# A non-blocking Poco HTTP server?

Tags: c++, c++11, network-programming, httpserver, poco-libraries

In Poco's documentation (https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.ServerApplication.html) there is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyServerApplication app;
    return app.run(argc, argv);
}
```

This would imply a standalone, blocking server application. However, my use case is that I'd like to integrate a HTTP server to my already existing C++ application and it should not block the rest of the application. Can I somehow just start the Poco server in its own thread?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: What should your application do while server waits for requests?

Comment: This would be just a configuration UI for an embedded application. The application does what it does in the mean time. Seems that I should just use HTTPServer directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ServerApplication` is meant to be its own `Application` since it inherits from [Application](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.Application.html).  This means it has its own main.

So it depends on what you want to do in your `ServerApplication`.

If you want something else to be the main function, don't use `ServerApplication`.  But if you want the benefits of option parsing and portable code, use `ServerApplication` and have it spawn your other code via a thread similar to [SampleServer](https://github.com/pocoproject/sandbox/blob/master/Configuration/Util/samples/SampleServer/src/SampleServer.cpp).

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

See [HttpTimeServerApp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/Net/samples/HTTPTimeServer/src/HTTPTimeServer.cpp)

It has an example Application that contains an [HTTPServer](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPServer.html).  Maybe you just want an **HTTPServer** to start in your existing app.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks!